# Apache rewrite url need help

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Hello everyone I need help for apache mode rewrite cause I'm novice and. Actually I don't know how to make this done.

here is mys problem

I have some urls that I want to edit them with apache

1-  mywebsite/category.php ---> I want that url to stay like it is 
 mywebsite/category.php?sid=categoryname ---> 
                                  mywebsite/category/categoryname.html

2- mywebsite/news.php --> No modification 
  mywebsite/news.php?view=1(2,3,4,5....etc id in the database) --->
                mywebsite/news/topic header.html 
topic header is the title of the news that will be called from the database via the id

Well Thanks everyone for you help cause really I don't know how to do this.
All what I can do is create a htaccess file ^^.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file put:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/category.php?sid=([^&]+) /category/$1.html [L,R]
```