# url in subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help me. How can I do for www.example.com/search.php?q=skipsoft to www.example.com/skipsoft?

Comment: Can you please tell us more. What exactly do you want here?

Comment: is this a .htaccess mod-rewrite question?

Comment: And how would you know that www.mydomain.com/some_existing_file_or_script is not a search? At least your search url should look something like www.mydomain.com/s/search_value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache rewrite url need help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880960/apache-rewrite-url-need-help)

Comment: @Dan Heberden: Sure it is, everytime you want to bend urls you need mod-rewrite. I've changed the tagging, because this question had nothing to do with php (the original and only tag).

Comment: I mean www.mydomain.com/author redirect to www.mydomain.com/search.php?q=author.

Comment: @skipsoft: I understand this, but still how do you distinguish between www.mydomain.com/something_but_not_an_author and www.mydomain.com/author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect everything you can do something like this in your `.htaccess` file if you're using apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1 [L,R]
```

But I would recommend something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/s/(.*)$ /search.php?q=$1 [L,R]
```

This will match www.yourdomain.com/s/author to www.yourdomain.com/search.php?q=author.

Comment: **L**: Last Rule, so no further rule will be checked.
**R**: Redirect

Answer (score 0):

Without using JavaScript (which is a bad idea to modify the essential parts of a website, e.g. search), you won't be able to make forms submit data to a page that's not in the form /pagename?q=query or w/e.

But if you'd just like to shave of the .php extension, this will do the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

In your .htaccess file, this will make it so that any file with a .php extension can be accessed without one.